# How to deny access to users for a file but not to the plugin which uses the file using htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a plugin which is using an xml file located in the plugin folder.

example.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myxml.xml

I want to deny access to the file for users but not to the plugin. If I type the URL I can read the file. I used the following in htaccess inside my plugin's folder

```
<Files ~ "\.xml$">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
```

I get the 403 error but the plugin cannot read the file

I used Options -Indexes as well

How can I fix this?

Comment: Best way to protect any files from the online users is putting these files out of the web space, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Files ~ "\.xml$">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from All
  Allow from localhost
</Files>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no effect, I get the 403 but the plugin cannot read the file

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if you place it in the main .htaccess. Then the file is not accessible from outside but accessible from the wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution for this issue is, Set proper file permission and user group. So all the application can access the file, but **Public Users** can't.
For more information visit [Linux File permission](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about this:

- Load the file from the filesystem and not over the network if possible.
- Use access control as [@Jamie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356657#answer-52357261) has suggested. 
  His code might not work if `example.com` doesn't resolve to `localhost` (check your */etc/hosts*). It the file has to be accessed over the public internet, use your public IP.

For reference, here is the documentation for [mod_access](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_access_compat.html).

> Access can be controlled based on the client hostname, IP address, or
>   other characteristics of the client request, as captured in
>   environment variables.

And you could also use [authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/auth.html) for that file.